# OptaPlanner to have a planningListVariable and a planningVariable in one planningEntity

Tags: optaplanner

We have a use case where we want to assign interviewers to meetings. Each meeting has a different number of interviewers and the meeting time is flexible.(We know the number of interviewers to be assigned for each meeting) We know the meeting time range and according to the optaplanner wiki, we will use Timegrain design pattern for the time range. We also know the interviewer availability range. We want to provide the suggestions of all meetings' meeting time and interviewers.
But currently, having a planningListVariable and a planningVariable in one planningEntity is not supported yet. I also checked using shadow variable or chain variable, but they sound not working.
Do you have any suggestions how to support it or how could I design the domain model?

```
public class MeetingAssignment {

    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    private Meeting meeting;

    //Planning variables: changes during planning, between score calculations
    @PlanningListVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "interviewerList")
    private List<Interviewer> interviewers = new ArrayList<>();

    @PlanningVariable
    private TimeGrain startingTimeGrain;
}
```

([Domain model design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kya0c.png))

I have tried running up the server but it fails as complaining about having a planningListVariable and a planningVariable in one planningEntity.
My another thought is that I could define the MeetingAssignment as:

```
public class MeetingAssignment {

    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    private Meeting meeting;

    //Planning variables: changes during planning, between score calculations
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "interviewerList")
    private Interviewer interviewer;

    @PlanningVariable
    private TimeGrain startingTimeGrain;
}
```

And then create more instances of MeetingAssignment(For the same meeting, it has several instances of MeetingAssignment). But the problem could be that how could enforce these MeetingAssignments to share the same meeting time if they actually have the same meeting? Maybe we could achieve it by constraint score, but that would waste time over it.
Do you have any suggestions how to support it or how could I design the domain model?

Comment: @LukášPetrovický

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem could be that how could enforce these MeetingAssignments to share the same meeting time if they actually have the same meeting?

This is the core of your problem. If you go down this road, the solver will be very inefficient, precisely because it will not be able to move all the meetings together. Every meeting move will break some hard constraint, making meaningful progress impossible.

The workaround to this is to use [filtered selection](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#filteredSelection) and only allow moves that move meetings together. This allows the metaheuristics to work efficiently, but the inefficiency will instead manifest in the move filters.

Planning list variable is very good for the use cases it does support, but there are unfortunately many use cases it doesn't yet. And that results in situations which are difficult to implement, just like yours.

Comment: Also, one day we'll support Move Streams. That will make it more practicable to do these kind of combinations.

Comment: Thanks @LukášPetrovický,  and Geoffrey De Smet ! Do you have some suggestion for this filtered selection. From the wiki, I get that the Move will only have access to one entity which is before/after move. But I cannot join it by two different entities. I want to join by some fields to know that they have the same meeting. I think  the Move will only have access to one entity which is before/after move might make sense because the move shouldn't know how other entities look like?

Comment: The selection filter has an argument `selection`, which - if you're filtering moves - will be of type `Move`. From there, you can cast to `ChangeMove`, `SwapMove` etc. And those specific types will have all the information you need.

Comment: Got it, will try it. Thanks!